# php ldap_bind returns error however ldapsearch console command works as exprected

Tags: php, linux, ldap

I'm having an issue with php function `ldap_bind`. After I `ldap_connect` to a server, I try to run a `ldap_bind` and get this error:

```
Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server.
```

I was wondering if there is some issue with php configuration because when I run the `searchldap` command with corresponding parameters, it works fine.

Thank you for the reply in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you try to connect without SSL/TLS, also - have you tried using adLDAP? It helped me out loads http://adldap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you have an success debugging the issue?

Comment: @friendly_programmer did you come up with anything in your situation?  Have same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467635/ldap-bind-fails-in-php-ldapsearch-works-from-command-line

Comment: @acoder I just worked around it by using exec() to run searchldap.

Comment: Mine turned out to be an obscure (to me) setting with SELInux:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490754/ldap-bind-fails-with-cant-contact-ldap-server